# Safari Auth0 Lock - Unable to configure verification page

Tags: angular, auth0, auth0-lock

it seems the auth0 lock ive implemented stopped working recently in safari. (Works in Chrome and Firefox).

I updated to the latest version, still has the same problem.

```
"auth0-js": "^9.8.0",
"auth0-lock": "^11.10.0",
```

This is the error message from the console.

> {error: "server_error", errorDescription: "Unable to configure
>   verification page.", state: "w5Eu5lhRuqQ_O-m284pB~sXDLwoZ6_Iz"} = $1

It hits the below "authorization_error" callback

```
this.lock.on('authenticated', (authResult: any) => {
    if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        console.log('HERE');
        this.setSession(authResult);
    }
});

this.lock.on('authorization_error', error => {
    console.log('Auth Failed', error);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone encountering the same issue, I have some bad news : you now have to pay for auth0 Lock(v11) embedded to work with third party cookies.
The solution is to use the hosted version of Lock, using the `authorize` method instead of `show()`.

The reason is that cross-origin authentication requires cross-domain cookies to establish an SSO session in the authorization server.

The documentation is very misleading regarding this.
With at least Safari & Brave blocking third party cookies by default, the free tier of Auth0 Lock is somewhat useless now.
Some more info on [this thread](https://community.auth0.com/t/unable-to-configure-verification-page-error-on-hosted-login/9214/29)

Comment: So annoying... spent days setting up my site with auth0-lock and did not realize it would not work on Safari at all.